# Replace some cell references, not all

Tags: excel

Want to use find and replace cell references. Ctrl-F and replace in formulas replaces all references or one cell at a time. I want to highlight a couple cells and only replace those.

```
eg..
cell B1 has formula = domestic!A5
cell B2 has formula = domestic!A6
cell B3 has formula = domestic!A7

I want it to be:
B1= domestic!A5
B2 = global!A6
B3= global!A7
Is there a way to this in excel 2013
```

Comment: Actually **Find&Replace** (CTRL+H) works exactly in the way you have described: if some cells (or rows or columns) are highlighted / selected, **Find&Replace** does its job only at those selected cells. This is valid for all versions of Excel, do you need anything else I could not get?

Answer (score 0):

I know you did not request a VBA Script, but it gives you an option unless anyone else has an alternative solution, this code will change the formulas as required on any selected cells:

```
  Sub ChangeFormulas()

    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim SelRng As Range

    Set SelRng = Application.Selection

    For Each Cel In SelRng.Cells

        Cel.Formula = Replace(Cel.Formula, "domestic!", "global!")

    Next Cel

  End Sub
```